# NAudio AsioOut + Sockets

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, audio, naudio

I'm newbie in audio programming and in sockets programming. I'm trying to send guitar signal over a network using NAudio AsioOut class and Sockets.

Here's source code of Receiver and Sender.

It seems like the receiver really gets the bytes array from sender, but all what I hear is white noise.

**Receiver source code**

```
    using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using NAudio.Utils;
using NAudio.Wave;
using NAudio.Wave.SampleProviders;

namespace Reciever
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static Socket Listener;
        private static Socket Accepter;
        private static AsioOut Output;
        private static BufferedWaveProvider OutputBuffer;
        [STAThread]
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPHostEntry ipHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry("192.168.1.4");
            IPAddress ipAddr = ipHostEntry.AddressList[2];
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 7777);
            Listener = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            Console.WriteLine("Слушатель готов по адресу:{0} ", ipEndPoint);
            Listener.Bind(ipEndPoint);
            Listener.Listen(10);
            Accepter = Listener.Accept();
            Console.WriteLine("Клиент с адресом {0} подключен", Accepter.RemoteEndPoint);

            Output = new AsioOut();
            Output.ShowControlPanel();
            Console.Read();
            OutputBuffer = new BufferedWaveProvider(WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(44100, 2));

            Output.Init(OutputBuffer);

            Thread playing = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Output.Play));
            Thread listening = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listening));

            playing.Start();
            listening.Start();
        }

        public static void Listening()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[65538];
                int ReceivedData = Accepter.Receive(buffer);
                OutputBuffer.AddSamples(buffer, 0, ReceivedData);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Sender source code**

```
    using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using NAudio.Wave;


namespace Sender
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Socket sck;

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AsioOut asioout = new AsioOut();

            IPHostEntry ipHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry("192.168.1.2");
            IPAddress ipAddr = ipHostEntry.AddressList[1];
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 7777);
            sck = new Socket(ipEndPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            BufferedWaveProvider buffer = new BufferedWaveProvider(WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(44100,2));
            sck.Bind(ipEndPoint);
            try
            {
                sck.Connect("192.168.1.4", 7777);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Соединие не установлено");
                Console.Read();
                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Соединение установлено");
            asioout.InitRecordAndPlayback(buffer, 2, 44100);
            asioout.AudioAvailable += new EventHandler<AsioAudioAvailableEventArgs>(asioout_AudioAvailable);
            asioout.Play();
            Console.Read();
        }

        private static void asioout_AudioAvailable(object sender, AsioAudioAvailableEventArgs e)
        {
            var samples = e.GetAsInterleavedSamples();
            byte[] OutputBuffer = new byte[e.SamplesPerBuffer*4];
            byte[] SendingBuffer = new byte[e.SamplesPerBuffer*4];
            Console.WriteLine(e.SamplesPerBuffer*4);
            for (int i = 0; i < e.InputBuffers.Length; i++)
            {
                Marshal.Copy(e.InputBuffers[i], OutputBuffer, 0, e.SamplesPerBuffer*4);
                Buffer.BlockCopy(samples, 0, SendingBuffer, 0, e.SamplesPerBuffer*4);
                Marshal.Copy(OutputBuffer, 0, e.OutputBuffers[i], e.SamplesPerBuffer * 4);

            }

            sck.Send(SendingBuffer);
            e.WrittenToOutputBuffers = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPD.1** (07.10.2015): Sender code and Receiver code are updated. Now I can hear the guitar signal from receiver, but it sounds very distorted. What I do wrong?

P.S. I'm using M-Audio Fast Track USB sound card on my desktop PC. The signal goes from that one to my laptop with ASIO4ALL driver over the network.

Answer (score 1):

Your receiver assumes that the incoming audio is 16 bit, but with ASIO, it could easily be 24 or 32 bit. In fact, your sending code seems to assume 32 bit. So start by trying to use an IEEE float WaveFormat on the receiving end

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Well in receiver I did that: bufferStream = new BufferedWaveProvider(WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(44100,2));
But I still hear the noise, and now that one sounds like distorted bass-guitar.

Comment: OK, well you really need to know exactly what format the samples are being recorded in. What bit depth, are they ints or floats? And how many channels?

Comment: 44100 Hz, 24 bit, 2 channels. e.AsioSampleType in Sender returns Int32LSB